# Reduce and clean code

Tags: wordpress

In wordpress category.php I have this code:

```
if ( is_category('cat-1') ) {
$the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'mueble', 'category_name' => 'cat-1' , 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) ) ;
}

if ( is_category('cat-2') ) {
$the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'mueble', 'category_name' => 'cat-2' , 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) ) ;
}

if ( is_category('cat-3') ) {
$the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'mueble', 'category_name' => 'cat-3' , 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) ) ;
}


while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
...
endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();
```

How can I simplify the code? I have 30 categories and too many conditionals isn't ideal...

Answer (score 0):

if you know the exact number of categories, you can try a for loop:

```
for ($x=0; $x<=30; $x++) {
    if ( is_category('cat-' . $x) ) { $the_query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'mueble', 'category_name' => 'cat-' . $x , 'posts_per_page' => 3 ) ) ; }
}
```